Can I build a portable execution environment with everything in `~/.local`?
I'm using multiple Linux servers that are running on different versions of glibc and other essential libraries. Since I do not have root access, I have to compile the packages from scratch on each machine. So I want to pack a local library environment from scratch (containing glibc) in ~/.local (i.e. --prefix=/home/<xxx>/.local) and completely discard system libraries.
Will this solution approachable? (i.e. I can pack the ~/.local and ~/.bashrc, move to a new machine, unpack them, and use them directly.)
Recently I'm reading Linux from Scratch, but actually this is not a cross-compiling task so procedure in the book may not apply. My current sequence is glibc -> binutils -> libstdc++ -> gcc. Is the order correct? What's the correct order of building libraries?

What you are describing is very much like how Nix operates. (Everything is stored under /nix/store, instead of ~/.local, and symlinks and PATH manipulation are used to make things accessible.)

This seems more appropriate to [unix.se] . Please delete here and move to there. OR you need to supply a [mcve] . Good luck.

I believe it's called a standalone directory.  Portable C libs / awesome-c Also, check out  mount --help --bind and the source options look useful.

Why not just a docker image?

Finally I've turned to Gentoo Prefix. After a few hours of compilation, I've got a working standalone environment with a package manager inside it.
